# What am i doing wrong in my c function

Tags: c

```
int SumBetween(int low, int high)
{
    int i;
    int end;
    int Ray[high - low];
    int sum;

    end = (high - low);

    for (i = 1; i = end; i++) {
        Ray[i] = low + i;
    }

    sum = 0;
    for (i = 1; i = end; i++) {
        sum = sum + Ray[i];
    }

    return sum;
}
```

The function above keep coming with this error:

```
main.c: In function 'SumBetween':
main.c:12:2: error: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Werror=parentheses]
for (i = 1; i = end; i++) {
^
main.c:17:2: error: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Werror=parentheses]
for (i = 1; i = end; i++) {
^
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why you have 2 assignments? You mean `for (i = 1; i < end....`? And try to start for loop with index 0 otherwise you will be out of bounds in array. Correct would be: `for (i = 0; i < end; i++)`

Comment: Or `i <= end`?.

Comment: is this `int Ray[high - low];` valid?

Comment: unrelated: What if `low` > `high` ?

Comment: `i = end` --> `i + low != end` ? or `i + low < end` ?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is not technically error, but a warning. In your case, all warnings are represented as errors, because compiler detected possible problem in your code.

As seen, you have a problem in your for loop:

1. First is meant as assignment, usually `i = 0` as arrays starts with `0` in C
2. This is condition, any assignment in condition *should* be in parenthesis
3. Third is increment or anything else (new assignment)

According to your code, you should rewrite your for loops to

```
//Start with i = 0 and go till end variable
//   1      2        3
for (i = 0; i < end; i++) {
    Ray[i] = low + i;
}
```

Comment: ...and note that arrays in C are from 0...n-1. So `for (i=1` is wrong.

Comment: No, I just added that his assumption about arrays in C was also wrong, which you fixed but didn't describe.

Answer (score 0):

Technically you're for() statement is a endless loop, if `end! = 0`.
Assuming that `high` is greater than `low` (or values is equal), you can avoid the second loop by doing as follows:

```
int SumBetween(int low, int high)
{
    int i, end, sum = 0;

    end = (high - low);

    for (i = 1; i != end; i++) {
        sum += low + i;
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Btw, my proposal relies on the assumptions that you are need to reach `end` value from `i = 1`